# How to return multiple lists in single call in WCF function using C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How to return multiple list in the single response from WCF function using C#.

Comment: What is the response format (xml, json, text, binary, ...) ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please see this article:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you start with code for how you are returning on List?

Answer (score 3):

Make a new class where all your lists are properties, and return that class from your `WCF` function.